# How to add information to an attribute table?

Tags: qgis, features, attribute-table, interpolation, sampling

I'm working with qgis 1.8.0 and did the following:

1.-Divided my shapefile into 830 features (small rectangles).
2.- Added to my shapefile several points containing weather information using the "add delimited text layer" tool. 
3.- Did some weather data interpolations. 
4.- Used the "point sampling tool" to collect the interpolated information for each and every one of the 830 features of the shapefile.

QUESTION: is there any way to add/import the information obtained with the point sampling tool to each of the 830 features of my original shapefile? I tried to modify the attribute table but couldn't find any way to paste information to a new column.. any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to do a spatial join.  But more information would be good.  A screen grab would really help.

Comment: Ryan I did exactly that. The problem is solved now. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad everything worked out.